# How do I add a legend to my chart that includes two series?

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following script creates a worksheet with two columns. From these two columns I created a chart. Then I tried to place a legend to the right of the axis but for some reason the legend is not seen. Can you please tell me why don't I see the legend ?

BTW, I have tried to methods to do that without any success (one of the is marked as a note)

```
chart = LineChart()
chart.title = "Device Time drift (2 samples/hour)"
chart.legend.position = 'r'
# chart.legend.layout = Layout(
#     manualLayout=ManualLayout(
#         yMode='edge',
#         xMode='edge',
#         x=0, y=0.9,
#         h=0.1, w=0.5
#     )
# )
chart.style = 10
chart.y_axis.title = 'Time Delta [mSec]'
chart.x_axis.title = 'Sample No.'
chart.legend = None
chart.height = 20  # default is 7.5
chart.width = 40  # default is 15

font = Font(typeface='Verdana')
size = 1200  # 14 point size
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font, sz=size, b=False)  # Not bold
pp = ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp)

# X and Y axes titles
chart.x_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].pPr = pp
chart.y_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].pPr = pp

data = Reference(worksheet=ws_write_timedel, min_col=1, min_row=1,
                 max_row=len(ws_write_timedel['A']), max_col=2, )

chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True,)
s1 = chart.series[0]
s1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "00AAAA"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.dashStyle = "sysDot"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.width = 100050  # width in EMUs

s2 = chart.series[1]
s2.smooth = True

ws_write_timedel.add_chart(chart, "D1")enter code here
```

Comment: Read about [Changing the layout of plot area and legend](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/chart_layout.html?highlight=chart%20legend)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The layout didn't do any effect. But I found the problem, the script includes the following line 'chart.legend = None' which is canceling the legend right after I defined it. I will fix the script and re-post it

Comment: Why `chart.legend = None`?

Comment: Probably it was there because I used this script once to prevent the legend to show. This time I copied the script and this line slipped from my sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script is the fixed version and now the legend is added to the chart

```
chart = LineChart()
chart.title = "Device Time drift (2 samples/hour)"
chart.legend.position = 'r'
chart.style = 10
chart.y_axis.title = 'Time Delta [mSec]'
chart.x_axis.title = 'Sample No.'
chart.height = 20  # default is 7.5
chart.width = 40  # default is 15

font = Font(typeface='Verdana')
size = 1200  # 14 point size
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font, sz=size, b=False)  # Not bold
pp = ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp)

# X and Y axes titles
chart.x_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].pPr = pp
chart.y_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].pPr = pp

data = Reference(worksheet=ws_write_timedel, min_col=1, min_row=1,
             max_row=len(ws_write_timedel['A']), max_col=2, )

chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True,)
s1 = chart.series[0]
s1.graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "00AAAA"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.dashStyle = "sysDot"
s1.graphicalProperties.line.width = 100050  # width in EMUs

s2 = chart.series[1]
s2.smooth = True

ws_write_timedel.add_chart(chart, "D1")enter code here
```